# Why won't $.getJson work with json or jsonp?

Tags: javascript, json, get, jsonp

I am trying to pull information from [Google Finances stock screener](https://www.google.com/finance?ei=sLqhVOieIsK68gbk-4GoDQ#stockscreener). There is no official api, so I am just making a get request to the same URL that they use on the site. I am using the URL at the bottom of the question, it can get a bit long. I can go to the url myself and it will give me a text file with the JSON information. In my javascript I am using `$.getJSON` on the url to get the screener results. But I get a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error, so I change `output=json` to `output=jsonp&callback=?`. But it only returns `();`. From what I can tell this means that it is not set up on the other end to respond to a jsonp request and cannot return the proper information. 
I have also tried `output=json&callback=?`, which produces the `();` and `output=json&callback=callbackFunction` and `output=json&callback=callbackFunction` which both give me `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. 
Is there any way that I can make this work?

https://www.google.com/finance?output=json&start=0&num=20&noIL=1&q=[currency%20%3D%3D%20%22USD%22%20%26%20%28%28exchange%20%3D%3D%20%22OTCMKTS%22%29%20%7C%20%28exchange%20%3D%3D%20%22OTCBB%22%29%20%7C%20%28exchange%20%3D%3D%20%22NYSEMKT%22%29%20%7C%20%28exchange%20%3D%3D%20%22NYSEARCA%22%29%20%7C%20%28exchange%20%3D%3D%20%22NYSE%22%29%20%7C%20%28exchange%20%3D%3D%20%22NASDAQ%22%29%29%20%26%20%28market_cap%20%3E%3D%200%29%20%26%20%28market_cap%20%3C%3D%200.1%29]&restype=company&ei=GLyhVKmcDpOb8gbm7IGQAQ

Answer (score 1):

If the service doesn't provide a JSONP endpoint or use CORS to grant you permission to access some other kind of endpoint, then there is no way to access the data using client side code.

Use server side code instead. You can use that to present the data to your client side code.